# Application of Borsuk-Ulam theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

As a consequence of Borsuk-Ulam theorem for $2$ dimensional case, we know that

> Whenever $S^2$ is expressed as the union of three closed sets $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$, then at least one of these sets must contain a pair of antipodal points $\{x,-x\}$.

I think this statement is still true for 'two' closed sets (no 'three' closed sets). But how can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, and relatively easy to prove given the above result.

If $S^2 = A_1 \cup A_2$, where $A_1, A_2$ are closed, then choose some closed $A_3$ that definitely doesn't contain a pair of antipodal points (e.g. let $A_3$ be a singleton set). Then $S^2 = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$, and $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are closed, so by the above result, $A_1$, $A_2$, or $A_3$ must contain a pair of antipodal points. Since $A_3$ definitely does not contain such a pair, it must be true of $A_1$ or $A_2$.